# Please help me to find the sample size?

Tags: sample-size

I conducte a survey in a state related to  perception regarding child sex ratio, for this I selecte the two district with high and low child sex ratio,now I travel with that how I selecte the sample size for each district if I want two blocks which are farthest and nearest from district headquarter.
I want to use proportional allocation.if any other then please answered.

Comment: If I understand your question, you want to perform the power analysis for test that compares two ratios (sex ratio in the first sample to the sex ration in the second sample). To conduct the power analysis you should state the expected effect size. I.e. what is the expected ratio in the first and in the second sample?

Comment: Actually I want to perform the chi square test to check is there any significance difference b/w perception of persons regarding dowry,crime against women etc with gender, category, religion wise.

Comment: And it is expected that total sample size should be 1280 for the whole state,